# "Divide by zero error" error after join in sql server (that doesn't add any rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server

First time asking a question here, I apologize if I make any mistakes.

Here's the thing, I have the following query that works just fine:

```
select *
, [ENERGIA_NETA_SMEC_MWH]*  [CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] * 9300 * 1000  / ( [CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] *9300 * 1000 + [CONSUMO_DE_GASOIL_M3] * 9211 +  [CONSUMO_DE_FUELOIL_T] * 10500 *1000 ) as 'Energia generada GN MWh '
from tabla_parte tp
```

The issue "Divide by zero error encountered." appears when I add a left join:

```
select *
, [ENERGIA_NETA_SMEC_MWH]*  [CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] * 9300 * 1000  / ( [CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] *9300 * 1000 + [CONSUMO_DE_GASOIL_M3] * 9211 +  [CONSUMO_DE_FUELOIL_T] * 10500 *1000 ) as 'Energia generada GN MWh '
from tabla_parte tp
left join cog.dbo.ParteDetalle pd
on tp.ParteID = pd.ParteID and pd.ItemID = 46
```

I can't seems to find out why the error appears, since the left join shouldn't add any rows. I've verified with with the following queries:

```
select count(1) from tabla_parte tp

select count(1) from tabla_parte tp
left join cog.dbo.ParteDetalle pd
on tp.ParteID = pd.ParteID and pd.ItemID = 46
```

Both of them give me the same number.

Since the left join isn't adding any rows, why does the error appear after the join?

Thanks!

Comment: Add some sample table data (that raises the error.) As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NULLIF()` to prevent divide-by-zero:

```
select *,
       ( ([ENERGIA_NETA_SMEC_MWH] *  [CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] * 9300 * 1000) /
         NULLIF([CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] *9300 * 1000 + [CONSUMO_DE_GASOIL_M3] * 9211 +  [CONSUMO_DE_FUELOIL_T] * 10500 *1000, 0) 
       ) as [Energia generada GN MWh]
from tabla_parte tp;
```

If one or both the tables are views, then the problem could be occurring in the view.

The cause of your problem might be that SQL Server can re-arrange calculations, pushing them closer to where it reads the data -- and before filters are applied.  This would be a particular issue if you have `WHERE` clauses somewhere (although these are not shown in your question).

Comment: Well, that seems to solve the issue. Thank you.
As you've said, this would make more sense if there was a where clause, but there isn't. Also, there are no views involved.
Still, I'll add the nullif and call it a day :)

Comment: @GustavoSchneider: if there are truly no views involved, and `SELECT * FROM tabla_parte where ( [CONSUMO_DE_GAS_DAM3] *9300 * 1000 + [CONSUMO_DE_GASOIL_M3] * 9211 +  [CONSUMO_DE_FUELOIL_T] * 10500 *1000 ) = 0` gives no rows, I'd still call this an optimizer bug. That it's free to rearrange expressions (necessitating them to evaluate correctly under every possible condition) is well known, but if it introduces div/0 errors due to the way it's handling joins is going too far.

Comment: You know, I ran that query yesterday after the proposed solution worded and found out there are tons of rows (>200000) that should've failed on the original query. Now I don't know why the error doesn't show on the original query (again, this is solved, I'm just curious)